# accessing elements of one iframe from another iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have one parent window and two iframes in it. I am trying to access elements of one iframe from
another iframe.Using the code:

```
function startplay(){
   var txt="";
   txt+= "some text";
   var tag = window.frames("plays").getElementById("myvideo");
   tag.innerHTML=txt;
}
```

the above code lies in an iframe script which is activated by anchor tag. but nothing happens on calling the script. myvideo tag content doesn't change. is it the correct way to access the elements of one iframe from another. 
should i use parent.document.getElementById("plays").getElementById("myvideo"); to get a ref. of myvideo.

code lies in iframe(playright) and myvideo tag lies in iframe(plays).

Comment: Are each of these iframes on the same site?  If they are not, google "XSS vulnerability"

Answer (score 5):

if you are within one of the iframes, you need to use "parent" to go to its parent, and from there reference the iframe object.

So this should work:

```
parent.nameofotheriframe.getElementById("myvideo");
```

(by using getElementById you were referencing the <IFRAME> tag, not the iframe object).

Comment: I did in my function: parent.playscreen.getElementById("myvideo"); playscreen is name attribute of my second iframe that contains the myvideo tag. Still no use. My function is ok since i can check it for its own iframe .

Comment: i hope you meant name not id.

Comment: it may be that my answer only works in IE. Does this work : parent.frames("playscreen").getElementById("myvideo")  ?

Comment: no it doesn't work. I had used somewhere in my code parent.document.getElementById("playright").contentWindow.getlist(listval,listname);  and it worked fine but this time even this statement doesn't do anything. don't go by the details i am just saying that such a statement worked for accessing the getlist function in playright iframe from the current iframe.

Comment: any idea regarding this statement ?

Comment: parent.document.getElementById("plays").contentDocument.getElementById("myvideo"); works for me on chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

**My main page code:**

```
<div id="left">
    <iframe id="leftframe" name="leftframe" src="iframe-left.html"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <iframe id="rightframe" name="rightframe" src="iframe-right.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Left frame:**

```
<div id="DivInLeftFrame">aaa</div>
```

**Right frame:**

```
<input type="button" value="clickme" onclick="changeLeftFrame();">
```

The function is:

```
changeLeftFrame(){
     parent.leftframe.document.getElementById('DivInLeftFrame').innerHTML = 'bbb';
}
```

add the 'document' to work.