# How to clear the contents of an iFrame from another iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a `wrapperPage.html` with an `<iframe class="header"` and `<iframe class="pageBody"`. In `header` there is a link, `<a class="clearLink"`, which when clicked should clear the contents of `pageBody`.

So far the following implementation of the above idea doesn't work. Please help me resolve this.

**Please NOTE** that, `header` and `pageBody` are each loaded from different included files.

**wrapperPage.html**

```
<div class=non-floater>
    <iframe class="header" src="header.html"></iframe>
    <iframe class="pageBody" src="pageBody.html" /> 
</div>
```

**header.html :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".clearLink").on("click", function() {
            $('.pageBody').contents().find("body").html('');
        });
    });
</script>

<a class="clearLink" href="#">Navigation Button</a>
```

**pageBody.html :**

```
<div class="panel-body">This is the body</div>
```

Comment: Tried using web worker ?

Comment: Do both iFrames on the same domain?

Comment: They are all the HTML files are stored in my local hard-disk in the same folder

Comment: This reply might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19187765/259889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Channel messaging](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#channel-messaging)

`wrapperPage.html`

```
<body>
<div class=non-floater>
    <iframe class="header" src="header.html"></iframe>
    <iframe class="pageBody" src="pageBody.html" /> 
</div>
<script>
  var channel = new MessageChannel();
  var header = $(".header")[0].contentWindow;
  var pageBody = $(".pageBody")[0].contentWindow;
  header.onload = function() {
    this.postMessage("","*", [channel.port2])
  };

  channel.port1.onmessage = function(e) {
    if (e.data === "clicked") {
      $(pageBody.document.body).html("")
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
```

`header.html`

```
<body>
<a class="clearLink" href="#">Navigation Button</a>
<script>
  var port;

  onmessage = function(e) {
    port = e.ports[0];
  }

  $(".clearLink").on("click", function(e) {
      port.postMessage("clicked");
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @guest271314. One last thing please. How can I go about selecting an element from inside an iFrame and adding some HTML into it, after getting an iFrame `var pageBody = $(".pageBody")[0].contentWindow;`. For example, an implementation like: `$(pageBody.document.body).contents().find(".someDIV").html('<div>DIV content</div>');`

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev Tried `$(pageBody.document.body).contents().find(".someDIV").html('<div>DIV content</div>');` ?

Comment: Yes. I've done it after loading a HTML, `pageBody.html`, then trying to add HTML into a DIV, `contentDIV` inside `pageBody.html`. This is the way I've gone about it: 
$(pageBody.document.body).load('pageBody.html');
$(pageBody.document.body).contents().find(".contentDIV").html('<div>Content...</div>');

Comment: Hi @guest271314. I just noticed that it actually loads the HTML, which then quickly disappears. What could be the problem?

Comment: Appear to be loading entire `html` documen t- same `html` document as existing `html` document - into `body` element of `pageBody` at `$(pageBody.document.body).load('pageBody.html');` ? , then replacing newly added document  with `'<div>Content...</‌​div>'` ? tried without `.load()` portion ? What is expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the reference of the main window from an iFrame as follow:
[Window.Parent reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/parent)

Then, you can assign an event to catch a trigger or a function in the main window (or only in the other iFrame) to manage it.

*For example :*

- Write a function in pageBody.html associated to a custom event.
- Get window reference from your click function in your `header.html` iFrame.
- Search target element which has your custom event assigned.
- Fire the event

I would hope it help you.