# Change a parent window's URL using history pushState when link in Iframe is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a page that has a header and sidebar with a right content panel that is an Iframe.

In a page loaded into the right content panel, I am trying to have a clicked link update the Browser URL in the parent window to the URL of the new page that is loaded into the Iframe.

I do not want the actual parent window to reload the URL but simply to update the URL in the address bar.

Something like:

```
window.history.pushState('obj', 'newtitle', '/bookmarks/list/');
```

Is this possible from an Iframe?

Comment: _"Is this possibble from an Iframe?"_ Have you tried this approach ?

Comment: @guest271314 I have tried it, it updated the URL of the Iframe, so my iframe loaded a new page and had the new URL but the parent URL never changed

Comment: I think I will try using the ifram `onmessage` events to send new url to parent from iframe and in the parent page, call the `window.history.pushState` from parent and see if that will do the magick

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-iframe-from-another-iframe/

Comment: @guest271314 that post is to change the content of a page.  I need to update the URL without reloading the page.  THe idea posted above worked though.  Using post message my parent receive the URL and then send a pushState to update the parent URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish updating the parent windows URL in the address bar using history.pushState by sending the new URL to the parent from the child Iframe window using `postMessage` and on the parent window listening for this event.

WHen the parent receives the child iframes `postMessage` event, it updates the URL with pushSTate using the URL passed in that message.

**Child Iframe**

```
<script>
// Detect if this page is loaded inside an Iframe window
function inIframe() {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}

// Detect if the CTRL key is pressed to be used when CTRL+Clicking a link
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which=="17")
        cntrlIsPressed = true;
});
$(document).keyup(function(){
    cntrlIsPressed = false;
});
var cntrlIsPressed = false;

// check if page is loaded inside an Iframe?
if(inIframe()){
    // is the CTRL key pressed?
    if(cntrlIsPressed){
        // CTRL key is pressed, so link will open in a new tab/window so no need to append the URL of the link
    }else{

        // click even on links that are clicked without the CTRL key pressed
        $('a').on('click', function() {

            // is this link local on the same domain as this page is?
            if( window.location.hostname === this.hostname ) {

                // new URL with ?sidebar=no appended to the URL of local links that are clicked on inside of an iframe
                var linkUrl = $(this).attr('href');
                var noSidebarUrl = $(this).attr('href')+'?sidebar=no';

                // send URL to parent window
                parent.window.postMessage('message-for-parent=' +linkUrl , '*');

                alert('load URL with no sidebar: '+noSidebarUrl+' and update URL in arent window to: '+linkUrl);

                // load Iframe with clicked on URL content
                //document.location.href = url;
                //return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

---

**Parent window**

```
<script>

// parent_on_message(e) will handle the reception of postMessages (a.k.a. cross-document messaging or XDM).
function parent_on_message(e) {
    // You really should check origin for security reasons
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage#Security_concerns
    //if (e.origin.search(/^http[s]?:\/\/.*\.localhost/) != -1
    //    && !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 7)) {
        var returned_pair = e.data.split('=');
        if (returned_pair.length != 2){
            return;
        }
        if (returned_pair[0] === 'message-for-parent') {
            alert(returned_pair[1]);
            window.history.pushState('obj', 'newtitle', returned_pair[1]);
        }else{
            console.log("Parent received invalid message");
        }

    //}
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Setup XDM listener (except for IE < 8)
    if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 7)) {
        // Connect the parent_on_message(e) handler function to the receive postMessage event
        if (window.addEventListener){
            window.addEventListener("message", parent_on_message, false);
        }else{
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", parent_on_message);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `Window.postMessage()`.

Iframe:

```html
<a href="/test">/test</a>
<a href="/test2">/test2</a>

<script>
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.parent.postMessage(this.href, '*');
  });
});
</script>
```

Main page:

```html
Current URL: <div id="current-url"></div>
<iframe src="iframe-url"></iframe>

<script>
const $currentUrl = document.querySelector('#current-url');
$currentUrl.textContent = location.href;

window.addEventListener('message', event => {
  history.pushState(null, null, event.data);
  $currentUrl.textContent = event.data;
});
</script>
```

See [demo on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhaqpms5/3/).