# Communicating data through webpages with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm new to web development and i have an issue with javascript.

On **webpage 1**,  I have a table displayed in javascript. Each element of the table can be clicked on, and will sent you to **webpage 2** displaying more information about this element.

How can i communicate the element which was clicked on **webpage 1** to **webpage 2**?
Is there a way to use &_GET and &_SORT of the php page containing my script, or is there an equivalent?

To be more precise, i'm switching between webpages through a listener:

```
function selectHandler(e) {
    window.location="display.php";
};
```

Comment: Are webpage 1 and webpage 2 at the same domain ?

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to mention it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-iframe-from-another-iframe/33649349

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If so necessary you can communicate them through URL hash:

```
//webpage 1
window.location="display.php#elem1";
//webpage 2
if (window.location.hash === '#elem1') {...}
```