# How to reference and access document object of a page redirected with window.location

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

In a current html page, I have an `onclick` event attached to a button, that will redirect to a new page. On that new page, I need to use `document.getElementById`... to make changes on the new page. As expected after redirection, `document.getElementById`... returns null maybe because it is still considering the previous page that doesn't have element with specified id.
I use :

```
window.location.assign(url_of_new_page);
document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML="SOMETHING";
```

The error here says:

> cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

Any hint on dealing with this would be appreciated!

Comment: Please give us an example with this problem so we can solve it faster.

Comment: You can use `storage` event, see [On hover show element from different page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555836/on-hover-show-element-from-different-)