# Accessing iframe parent within iframe without id

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

im creating modal windows with iframes inside of them dynamicly with js and im trying to figure out how i can get parents of that iframe from within to be able to manipulate that iframe specific window. Is it possible?

For example - main page will create 2 same divs with iframe inside

```
<div class="window"><iframe src="./testPage.html"></iframe></div>
<div class="window"><iframe src="./testPage.html"></iframe></div>
```

And i want to modify/remove or just simply get this $(".window") from testPage.html (iframe) but only that one which contains iframe where is testPage im actualy calling this script on (not both divs).

I hope it is understandable, sorry for my english :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but that will not say what iframe it is...

Comment: @Liam does not answer OPs question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the OPs question then?

Comment: i just want to get element one level up from iframe im currently in no id provided (element containing iframe im currently in)

Comment: OP has code running in the iframe. OP wants to access the parent and get a reference to that iframe.

Comment: `parent.$(".window").each( function(){
    console.log(this.contentWindow==window);
} );`

Comment: You can use `MessageChannel`, see [How to clear the contents of an iFrame from another iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-iframe-from-another-iframe)

Comment: @epascarello thanks, this seems to be working fine, if nobody knows more elegant way i will accept it as answer, anyway thx, you saved me from hedache :)