# CORS - Cross Origin Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, call

I don't know what I do wrong but basically. CORS is more than rocket science to me. **I tried to make it work with PostMessage but it worked only for Chrome so I gave up on it too. Microsoft Edge did not respond to the eval of the code and Firefox dropped a notice**

Only in german the error message of firefox.

> Anfrage für Vollbildmodus wurde abgelehnt, weil
>   Element.mozRequestFullScreen() nicht aus einem kurz laufenden
>   Benutzer-generierten Ereignis-Handler aufgerufen wurde.

---

What I want to do:

Send the "SetFullscreen(1);" Function to an iframe to make it work. The iframe is hosted on a https sub-domain of my site

http://www.spiele-umsonst.de/zombie-derby-2-t6058.html The Full-Screen Button above the game

should execute the same way it would onthe iframe. Simple as that..

https://gameshtml5.spiele-umsonst.de/unitywebgl/zombiederby2/
The iframe has a unity-fullscreen function which can be called SetFullscreen(1);. But I want to call this function on my own button on the parent page.

My faboulous header that I thought would work for the https site:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *.spiele-umsonst.de
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    origin, x-requested-with, content-type
```

> zombie-derby-2-t6058.html:589 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame
>   with origin "http://www.spiele-umsonst.de" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame.
>       at fullscreen (http://www.spiele-umsonst.de/zombie-derby-2-t6058.html:589:48)
>       at HTMLDivElement.onclick (http://www.spiele-umsonst.de/zombie-derby-2-t6058.html:418:199)

Comment: See [How to clear the contents of an iFrame from another iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-iframe-from-another-iframe/33649349?s=15|0.0000#33649349)

Comment: Yeah this doesn't seem like a CORS problem but a problem on how you're trying to have an iframe talk to the parent frame.

Comment: I don't understand german, but the FF error looks like it says something along *mozRequestFullscreen must be called by an user's gesture*  which means that you can't call it programmatically, from outside of an gesture event flow.

Comment: Also you'll need to set the `allowFullscreen` attribute on the iframe if you want to make one of its elements in fS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are currently facing has nothing to do with CORS, but with the Fullscreen API's limitation requiring an user-gesture to perform a fullscreenRequest, and with Chrome, which treats the message event synchronously, *(yes, this seems to be a chrome bug)*.

The current workflow is as follow :

- click frame1. (fullscreen request should be allowed)
- postMessage frame2. (we're still within the click handler so it should be good too).
- frame2 handles `message` event. (This should happen asynchronously, so our click event is broken and the fullscreen request should throw an error.

You can verify this in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LZBV5aMwpwsNSf0Cfjcg?p=preview) which uses synchronous [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent(event)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) method, unfortunately, unavailable on cross-origin frames.

---

#### Workarounds

If you were loading your iframe from the same domain, you could simply call the `element.requestFullscreen()` from the main frame, by accessing `element` through

```
iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('element').requestFullScreen();
```

This would work since the click event would not have been broken yet.

You could also use the `dispatchEvent` trick, but would make no such sense.

---

But in case of cross-origin frames, I didn't find any way to pass any [trusted event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation) from the main frame to the cross-origin one synchronously.

This means that you need to get a second event, this time originating from the framed document itself, to be able to call `requestFullscreen` on your targeted element. This can be achieved with a splash screen :

[plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FdNqbryvQ3R1DhmIbU9z?p=preview)

Or you could also only request the fullscreen on the `<iframe>` element itself, and then change the inner document's style so that your targeted element looks like it was fullscreened.

[plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nQwrfyXoH2qxzZyMlP00?p=preview)

Comment: recv.contentWindow.dispatchEvent(event); <-- This one causes a CORS-Problem error

Comment: @Spiele-Umsonst, that's what I was afraid of... Then you don't have so much solutions... I gave you two more in an edit to my answer, but they're not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Like I Said before. I tried postmessage:

This is on the iframe-side

```
    <script>//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function() {
    var messageEle = document.getElementById('message');

    function receiveMessage(e) {
        if (e.origin !== "http://www.spiele-umsonst.de")
            return;
       eval(decodeURI(e.data));
    }
    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
}
//]]></script>
<div id="message"></div>
```

and this on the parent-page

```
try{
        var recv = document.getElementById('myid').contentWindow;
        function sendMessage(e) {

        recv.postMessage('SetFullscreen(1);', 'https://gameshtml5.spiele-umsonst.de/unitywebgl/tankscifibattle/');
    }
    sendMessage();
        }
    catch(err){
        console.log('No UnityWebgl found');
        };
```

This will send the SetFullscreen(1); to the iframe and will than be eval'd.
This works fine on chrome, drops a note in firefox as above and does nothing in microsoft edge

Comment: Is this an answer ? Otherwise, you may want to add this info as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43595001/edit).

Comment: It's part of an answere that works for chrome. Still waiting if there is someone who can solve one of those cases and can tell the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

bascially I used another way now. This may not work on every game but on Unity games it works:

Also Thanks to Kaido. This is only a workaround. The main problem to call a function on the iframe failed ;)

1. I set Fullscreen to the Iframe on the parent

   ```
   var recv = document.getElementById("myid");        
   function toggleFullScreen() {
   if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
     if (recv.mozRequestFullScreen) {
       recv.mozRequestFullScreen();
     } else {
       recv.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
     }
   } else {
     if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
       document.mozCancelFullScreen();
     } else {
       document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
     }
   }   
   } toggleFullScreen();
   ```
2. Change the inner width and height of the canvas in it's ratio on resize in the iframe module. Maybe I could just call the SetFullscreen(1); on resize. Don't know if it's mentioned as a user gesture than.

   ```
   window.onresize = function(){
   reportSize();
   document.getElementById('canvas').style.width = newWidth + 'px';
   document.getElementById('canvas').style.height = newHeight + 'px';
   }

   function reportSize() {
   realw = document.getElementById('canvas').width;
   realh = document.getElementById('canvas').height;
   myWidth = 0; myHeight = 0; newWidth = 0; newHeight = 0;
   if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
   myWidth = window.innerWidth;
   myHeight = window.innerHeight;
   newWidth = myWidth;
   newHeight = Math.round(newWidth*parseInt(realh)/parseInt(realw)); 
   if (newHeight >  myHeight)
       {
       newHeight = myHeight; 
       newWidth = Math.round(newHeight*parseInt(realw)/parseInt(realh));
       }
   }
   ```

   }