# How can I get an element outside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, getelementbyid

I have the code below. `myscript.js` is embedded in `https://example.com/iframe3.html`. The `iframe3.html` is embedded in `homepage.html`. My question is, how can I change `myscript.js` so it will grab content outside its iframe. Essentially I am trying to grab `id="name"` and `id="age-i"`.

---

**myscript.js**

```
    var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
    var theage = document.getElementById("age-i").innerHTML;
    ifr.src = "https://example.com/get.php?age-i=" + theage;
    ifr.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(ifr);
```

---

**homepage.html**

```
<td width="340" align="right">
  <div id="userarea">
    <div>
      <div id="userarea-line1">
        <a href="#"><img src="/common/img/icons/home.png" width="14" height="14" /></a> <a id="name" href="#"><span class='notranslate'>John</span></a> | <a href="#">Account</a> | <a href="#" style="margin-right:5px;">Smith</a> </div>
      <div id="userarea-line2"> <img width="10" height="11" src="/common/skin/base/icons/icn_age.gif" />&nbsp; <span class="age-format"> <a href="#"><strong id="age-i"><span class='notranslate'>26</span></strong> age</a>
      </span> <img width="10" height="11" align="top" src="/common/skin/base/icons/icn_age.gif" /> <span class="age-format" style="margin-right:5px;"> <span id="month-i"> <span class='notranslate'>03</span> </span> month</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<iframe id="myframe_content" frameborder="0" src="https://example.com/iframe3.html" name="myframe_content"></iframe>
```

---

**iframe3.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Anyone know? I still haven't figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I believe the existing stackoverflow post: [accessing elements of one iframe from another iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955413/accessing-elements-of-one-iframe-from-another-iframe) should answer your question.

Thanks,
Chetan

Comment: Bu the thing is, what is the name of the frame `age-i` is in? Its not in a frame technically? Could you give me an example of how it would work in my situation?

Comment: I see. In your code, the element with id `age-i` just belongs to the main page. So you could try with `window.parent.getElementById("age-i")` from the `myscript.js`. The window.parent here refers to the main page (so the iframe is child of it)

Comment: Hey, please also try `parent.getElementById("age-i")`. You may not need the `window.parent.getElementById()`